# More help needed with my image replacement javascript - add array object as a class

Tags: javascript

Apologies here is another question regarding my javascript image replacement script.
So far with the help of stackexchangers i have this like so and it's working great. But now I need to make another little change:

```
    var paths = ["add","clear","copy","delete"];


    var fullPaths = paths.map(function(x) { return "img[src*='" + x + "']"; } );
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(fullPaths);

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var img    = imgs[i],
            iClass = img.className,
            iSrc   = @@@THE CORRESPONDING NAME IN THE ARRAY@@@,
            span   = $('<span />', {'class': 'iconfont '+iClass+' '+iSrc,
                                    title  : img.parentNode.title
                     });

        $(img).replaceWith(span);
    }
```

I want `iSrc` to be the name of the image in the array. So that when the image with `<src="edit.png" class="iconmini>` is replaced, the span has the classes: `.iconfont`, `.iconmini`, and, `.edit`

I have tried doing the following:

```
iSrc   = paths[i]
```

but that doesn't work obviously and adds the wrong classes :)

I have another question, too, regarding my script but I will ask that as a seperate question. Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks again for everyone who has helped me here. I have now added an extra bit to my code that will also set the image title, and thought that I would post it here, it might help someone in the future.

Some of the images have titles and some dont like when they wrapped in an anchor. So I have done the following which seems to work for me:

```
var paths = ["add","clear","copy","delete"];

var fullPaths;
        var imgs;   
        for(var p=0; p<paths.length; p++) {    
            fullPaths = "img[src*='" + paths[p] + "']";
            imgs = document.querySelectorAll(fullPaths);
            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
                var img    = imgs[i];
                    if ($(img).attr('title')) {
                        iTitle = img.title;
                    } else {
                        iTitle = img.parentNode.title;
                    }

                    iClass = img.className;
                    iSrc   = paths[p];
                    span   = $('<span />', {'class': 'iconfont '+iClass+' '+iSrc,
                                            title  : iTitle
                             });
                $(img).replaceWith(span);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also, looking at your previous questions, what was wrong with `img.src.split('/').pop();` ?

Comment: the problem with that was that there are so many different ways that image sources are generated by this particular CMS - some dont have the folder in the source name, some dont have the whole path and only part of the name :)

Comment: Okay, but img.src always gives you the absolute path (non-relative)--img.getAttribute('src') is what gets you the original src attribute from the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the images separately for each path/class, so they won't be mixed:

```
var paths = ["add","clear","copy","delete"];
var fullPaths;
var imgs;   
for(var p=0; p<paths.length; p++) {    
    fullPaths = "img[src*='" + paths[p] + "']";
    imgs = document.querySelectorAll(fullPaths);
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var img    = imgs[i],
            iClass = img.className,
            iSrc   = paths[p],
            span   = $('<span />', {'class': 'iconfont '+iClass+' '+iSrc,
                                    title  : img.parentNode.title
                     });
        $(img).replaceWith(span);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great, from your part. Although it does not work when the parent of the <img> is a td/table cell :( I guess I did not think of that. In case of a table cell, the image replacement works fine, but it does not add the title, it just creates <title =""> .

Comment: oops no, I am being a right mug here. the <title> needs to come from the <img> and not the parent. I will play around with this a bit and get back to you soon!

Answer (score 3):

This is the same approach that @bfavaretto suggested but with the use of jQuery loops and simplified a bit:

```
var paths = ["add", "clear", "copy", "delete"];
$.each(paths, function (i, path) {
    $("img[src*='" + path + "']").each(function () {
        var $span = $('<span />', {
            class: 'iconfont ' + this.className + ' ' + path,
            title: this.parentNode.title
        });
        $(this).replaceWith($span);
    });
});
```

Comment: I just noticed jQuery is being used in the OP, so your version should be the way to go.

Comment: i'm just working through these answers now and seeing what works. I don't have jQuery installed though!

Comment: @user1525612 your original code uses jQuery to create the span doesn't it? and to do the replacement

Comment: oh god yes, i do have jQuery running here, but i should really turn it off as I shoudl be working with YUI or pure javascript only. sorry mate i am now extremely confused here!

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyways, I will try to convert my jQuery that I have atm to YUI using rosetta stone!

Answer (score 1):

I like bfavaretto's answer, but if you don't want to get the images separately, you could always add this lame-ish workaround:

```
var paths = ["add","clear","copy","delete"];


var fullPaths = paths.map(function(x) { return "img[src*='" + x + "']"; } );
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(fullPaths);

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var img    = imgs[i],
        iClass = img.className;
        //workaround start
        var iSrc;
        for(var j = 0; j < paths.length; j++) {
            if(img.src.split('/').pop().indexOf(paths[i]) != -1) {
                iSrc = paths[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        //workaround end
        span   = $('<span />', {'class': 'iconfont '+iClass+' '+iSrc,
                                title  : img.parentNode.title
                 });

    $(img).replaceWith(span);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again mate, with this approach I get the a class of 'undefined' added to my <span>. Maybe because I do not use the "folder/" bit in my array anymore?

Comment: Sorry about that. The function used should have been "split" not "slice". Whoops. Good luck!